# How to test $element in AngularJS controller using Karma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having a problem were I have a controller in my app which I use like `<div ng-controller='LogbookEditCtrl'> </div>` and this controller has a $element provider in it which I need to modify the element.

```
describe('LogbookEditCtrl', function(){
  'use strict';

  beforeEach(module('logbooks.edit'));


  it('should create "logbook" model', inject(function($controller) {
    var scope = {},

    // THIS EXPLODES BECAUSE IT SAYS THE $element PROVIDER WAS NOT FOUND, because there
    // is no html element of course..the controller is being created on its own.
    ctrl = $controller('LogbookEditCtrl', {$scope: scope});

  }));

});
```

I have tried something like the following, but it again says the $element provider was not found :

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$element_) {
  var element = compile('<div></div>');
  $element = element;
}));
```

Comment: Have you included the elementprovider .js file in your test? Even if you mock it, it needs to be included.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receiving?

Comment: The error is : Error: Unknown provider: elementProvider <- element

Comment: And what do you mean by elementprovider.js Jan? I have not come across that, dont know what you mean.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You would need to pass that dependency itself, since it refers to the bound element of the controller. And there is no `$element` provider available in angular (much similar to `$scope` as these are dynamic special dependencies provided by the app injector). You could create an element object using angular.element and pass it in as locals to the controller constructor,something like this.

```
var scope = {}, 
    element = angular.element('<div></div>'); //provide element you want to test

ctrl = $controller('LogbookEditCtrl', {$scope: scope, $element:element });
```

*This opens up the fact that why is it not recommended to use `$element` inside a controller and perform any DOM operation in them.*

Comment: "This opens up the fact that why is it not recommended to use $element inside a controller and perform any DOM operation in them."

This is no longer valid. Obviously avoid direct DOM manipulation but when following component architecture you don't really have another choice... at least not a better one.

Comment: @MikeHaas It is still valid IMHO. Especially if following proper component patterns and practices, you wont not need to do this in most places but obviously there might be some exceptions. If you need DOM manipulation then use directives instead. There is use for both sugars in today's world Also this is clearly mentioned in the [doc as well](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), please read the first section itself.

Comment: You're right there may still be times that a regular directive is needed but otherwise you're wrong. I could point you to source after source but don't have the time so I'll leave a few nuggets of info. Read that page from the angular docs again, and pay attention to mentions of the DOM. Notice how you can modify the DOM in neat ways using lifecycle hooks? Why do you think $element and such were created as injectables? It's so that the DOM can be manipulated from the controller itself. Even angular core has directives that do this.

Comment: @MikeHaas You can show me "code after code" if only i have time to look at it :) but that does not really mean something is right or something is wrong. It is an opinionated framework and hence you have the ability to do many things, need not always mean you go ahead and do it all the time. :) In my experience, i have written components, directives etc and rarely i had to mix component behavior logic in component controller with DOM specific behavior as i tend to follow SRP as much as possible, if at all i have a need to perform some custom DOM stuff.

Comment: Based on your comment "Obviously avoid direct DOM manipulation but when following component architecture you don't really have another choice" --> It is clear that you may have some missing points between a component architecture and direct DOM access, Component architecture with ng/react or any framework does no need you to access and manipulate DOM directly, they provide you abstractions to DOM by means of databindings etc.. I rest my case! :)